# How to install java (JDK) on snappy?

Tags: java, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, snapcraft

I am new to Snappy Ubuntu Core, I am building a system which client & server part. In client part I need to install a Java Application Agent. My client device using raspberry-pi-2 and I install Snappy on that. 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/
But my client part need to install java (something like openJDK) to communicate with server part.
I try to search java in snappy repo but dont have any results.
"sudo snappy search java, jdk..."
I have searched many times on google, but don't have suitable result. Please help me!

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can install JDK using the archives supplied by Oracle at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-arm-downloads-2187468.html. You need to choose the soft float package after accepting the terms. Follow the Readme for details after downloading and unzipping the file on your Pi.

Although the runtime will work fine, the Pi is a bit under powered for compilation using the development kit.

Answer (score 1):

Java isn't available as a snap yet, but you can download and extract  precompiled 32-bit (The pi2 is 32-bit) ARM java distribution (Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI) is available from oracle, [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).  Extract the tar file and look in the extracted directory's bin folder to find the java binaries.